# What do these SMD crystal labels mean?

Tags: identification, crystal

I’m trying to identify these 32.768 crystals from the label but can’t find them. What do these markings such as 32C446 and [32C416](http://www.newark.com/abracon/abs25-32-768khz-t/crystal-32-768khz-12-5pf-8-x-3/dp/13J1804?st=Crystal%2032.768%20SMD) mean? The actual part I want to identify is marked with 32C446.

Comment: Contact Abracon, find your local FAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be. Manufacturer id code, production year and week.
http://cfd.citizen.co.jp/english/prod-tech/product/pdf/datasheet_TF/CM200C_E.pdf

[image]